# Sinon test error with whois-json

Tags: typeerror, sinon, whois

I have a service API which up until recently used the whois library to get data.
I use sinon to test the API:

```
const mockWhoisLookup = sinon.mock(whois);
mockWhoisLookup
  .expects('lookup')
  .once()
  .withArgs('deals.dk')
  .callsFake((domain, callback) => {
    callback(undefined, whoisSampleResponse);
  });
```

I've decided to use whois-json instead as it provides a 'cleaner' output.
The issue is that when I now run the test it gives me an error output:

TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property lookup as function

```
  61 |     const mockWhoisLookup = sinon.mock(whois);
  62 |     mockWhoisLookup
> 63 |       .expects('lookup')
  64 |       .once()
  65 |       .withArgs('deals.dk')
  66 |       .callsFake((domain, callback) => {
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that in your new library the method to call is "lookup"?

Comment: The new library exports a module: 'module.exports = async function(domain, options)', and I don't really know how to deal with it.

Comment: You will probably need to mock this async function.